# write values into dataframe line by line too slow

Tags: python, dataframe

I have a dataframe like this:

```
df1=

Customer | Item | Qty   
----------------------
001      |A     | 3   
001      |B     | 3    
002      |C     | 4  
002      |D     | 8 
...      |...   |...
```

I want to get the transform the dataframe into format like this:

```
df2=

Customer | A | B | C | D |...   
-----------------------------
001      | 3 | 3 | 0 | 0 |...
002      | 0 | 0 | 4 | 8 |...
```

I do this through the following codes:

```
customer_list=list(set(df1.Custmer.values))
item_list=list(set(df1.Item.values))
df2=pd.DataFrame(columns=["Customer"]+item)
df2["Customer"]=customer_list
for index in df1.index:
    df2.loc[df2["Customer"]==df1.loc[index,"Customer"],df1.loc[index,"Item"]]=df1.lic[index,"Qty"]
```

However, my original data is very large, df1 has 1000000+ rows, that makes my program works very slow. I want to know whether there is any other quick method to get the result. Thank you!

Comment: If your numpy array data is in numpy multidimensional array before being placed in the pandas dataframe, you can use .T to transpose rows and columns. For your purpose, it would be a matter of transposing select subarrays before placing in the dataframe.

Answer (score 0):

Your feeling is correct. In general when using pandas or numpy looping is usually an inferior approach, because the whole point of using those libraries is to handle datasets in a more efficient manner than looping over every single row.

The method you are looking for is pivot as described here.
https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html

In code this would look like this:

`df2 = df1.pivot(index='Customer', columns='Item', values='Qty')`